# EFI sig list converter or viewer

Tags: uefi, ssl, efi, secure-boot

I recently used `efitools`' `keytool.efi` to save the EFI secure boot keys from my UEFI firmware. I now have a few `.esl` files that contain EFI signature lists, but they are binaries, and I would like to take a look at the content in a readable format.

Apparently these signatures generally start out as X.509 certificates and get converted to `.esl` using a tool such as `cert-to-efi-sig-list`; Is there a way to go backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a nice little [EFI utility](https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2018/blob/master/MyApps/ListCerts/ListCerts.efi) written by fpmurphy that prints human-readable information about the keys on a system and he wrote an informative blog post about this as well.

Answer (score 6):

The [efitools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jejb/efitools.git) package contains the `sig-list-to-certs` tool, which allows you to extract DER-encoded X.509 certificates from the `.esl` files (e.g. to extract and print out the first KEK certificate):

```bsh
efi-readvar -v KEK -o 'old_kek.esl'
sig-list-to-certs 'old_kek.esl' 'oldkek'
openssl x509 -in 'oldkek-0.der' -inform der -noout -text
```

Repeat the `openssl` command with `oldkek-N.der` for the other certificates, if there are more than one. Pass `PK`, `db`, and `dbx` to `v-` in the `efi-readvar` command to read the platform key and db white- and blacklists respectively.

Comment: This works for certificates. For hashes (such as in the dbx) you can pass them through `xxd -p -c32 < $basefile-0.hash`. The manpage for this tool is entirely unhelpful.